# How can I compare two tables with same structure and find unmatched records with mySQL?

Tags: mysql, compare

I have two tables with same structure.

```
TABLE-1
--------
ID  NAME
1   AAAA
2   BBBB
3   CCCC
4   DDDD

TABLE-2
--------
ID  NAME
1   AAAA
2   BBBB
3   CCCC
4   DDDD
5   eeee
6   ffff
7   gggg
8   hhhh
9   iiii
```

How I can compare this tables with MySQL and adding unmatched rows from TABLE-2 in TABLE-1?

Comment: Are those in the same database ? because if they are not have you considered replication ?

Comment: The second table is an alternative to the first table. The second table is loaded from a text file and scroll through files takes time. The second table is just temporary, which will be updated first. I hope you understand me.

Comment: Then the insert statements I provided below should work. It will add all the rows that id is found in table 2 and does not exist in table 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Insert into table-1 (select id,name from table-2 where id not in (select id from table-1));`

Answer (score 1):

If any of the `ID`, `NAME` is defined as unique key or combined unique (e.g `primary key (ID, NAME)`) Then its possible to utilize `INSERT IGONRE .. SELECT`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

If they are key, duplicate columns will be ignored while inserting as we are using `INSERT IGNORE`

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer.
This code working correctly and returnig unmatched rows.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE-1
WHERE TABLE-1.ID
NOT IN (
SELECT TABLE-2.ID
FROM TABLE-2
WHERE TABLE-2.ID=TABLE-1.ID
)
```