# How can I compare two tables with same structure and find unmatched records with Realm?

Tags: android, realm

It's quite easy for [SQL-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584885/how-can-i-compare-two-tables-with-same-structure-and-find-unmatched-records-with) systems but, how to do it with Realm on Android? Do I really have to iterate both tables like:

```
foreach(TABLE-1)
    foreach(TABLE-2)
        if(TABLE-1.item == TABLE-2.item) ...
        else ...
```

Why do I need it? I parse a list of pending articles with ids, and get say `1, 2, 3`. I store them in `TABLE-1` with state `PENDING`. After I while I parse the list of pending articles again, and this time I get say `2, 3, 4`. So I have to go through the newly fetched articles and check:

- which are already in `TABLE-1` (so I update content of `2, 3` with newly downloaded content)
- which are not in `TABLE-1` (so I add `4` to `TABLE-1` with state `PENDING` as it's new)
- which were in `TABLE-1` but were not fetched anymore (so I move article `1` to state `FINISHED` as it's not on results fetched from pending list).

So my idea was to store those newly parsed articles `2, 3, 4` in `TABLE-2` and just compare it with `TABLE-1`.

Comment: May I ask why do you need that?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: You can actually set some flag in the `Article`, like `pending`. So you can set/clear the flag when parsing which is the only iteration you need to do. Also, maybe you can have a `Date` field in the object (like `Date lastUpdated`). By combining different `RealmQuery`conditions, I think you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Your two tables should be merged into one class, then you can use `RealmQuery` to decide which elements you want based on the flags that determine the current state of the given item.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with Realm, but you also don't need to in the first place. You can solve this problem with just one schema class, and properly defined queries / flags that indicate status.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to, Realm does not support a "Schema" comparison like that!
Realm is a mobile DB, there's no need to have 2 schemas with the same structure!

Comment: "there's no need to have 2 schemas with the same structure" can you make it more clear as I don't get this part of your answer, thanks.

Comment: You don't have a computer, you have a phone, one of the principle of the mobile programming is to keep app light, so, why do you need 2 schemas with the same structure? In Realm this mean you have 2 classes with the same structure(params), and there's no point in this! Just store every entry in one schema!

Comment: I updated the question to explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: You just can use a primary key in entries, so, you fetch 1,2,3 the first time, and you store them in Realm, when you fetch again, you get 2,3,4, you do: insertOrUpdate(entry) so you'll update the entries you already have in the Realm, and insert the new ones! And that's all!

Comment: Read my question more carefully, what your "algorithm" misses is this part "which were in TABLE-1 but were not fetched anymore (so I move article 1 to state FINISHED as it's not on results fetched from pending list)." And please stop overusing EXCLAMATIONS!

Comment: Just check if the entries you already have in your realm are inside the list of fetched entries, if so, update them, if not set a boolean flag 'finished' to true, and you're done